# Creating playable DASH video encrypted with Clear Key encryption

Tags: encryption, video-streaming, html5-video, mpeg-dash

I am attempting to transcode and DASH (with Clear Key encryption) a [sample H.264](http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_h264.mov) file for the [Google Shaka player](https://github.com/google/shaka-player). Every set of steps I've been able to piece together online results in a playable version if unencrypted, then breaks down when I attempt to layer in encryption.

#### Unencrypted

Here are the steps I follow for the working unencrypted version:

1. Separate video from audio

   ```
   ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -an -c copy video_only.mp4
   ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0:2 -c copy audio_only.m4a
   ```
2. Transcode the video into a working variant (only 1 for now)

   ```
   ffmpeg -i video_only.mp4 -an -vcodec libx264 -s 1280x720 -c:v libx264 -b:v 384k -bf 2 -g 90 -sc_threshold 0 -an -strict experimental video_only_384kbps.mp4
   ```

3a. Create the mpd

```
    MP4Box -dash 5000 -segment-name 'outputseg-%s' -url-template -bs-switching no \
        -out output.mpd -rap \
        audio_only.m4a \
        video_only_384kbps.mp4
```

4a. Load the video into Osmo4 or Google Shaka
It plays.

#### With Encryption

Now, I attempt to layer in encryption. Starting from after step 2 above:

3b. Encrypt the variants with Clear Key

```
    MP4Box -crypt drm.xml audio_only.m4a -out audio_only_encrypted.m4a
    MP4Box -crypt drm.xml video_only_384kbps.mp4 -out video_only_384kbps_encrypted.mp4
```

where drm.xml contains a sample derived straight from the [MP4Box/GPAC site](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/encryption/common-encryption/):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <GPACDRM type="CENC AES-CTR">
      <!-- example for GPAC - keys are listed after the content and UL follows -->
      <DRMInfo cypherIV="0x00000000000000000000000000000001" cypherKey="0x6770616363656E6364726D746F6F6C31" cypherOffset="9" type="pssh" version="1">
        <BS ID128="6770616363656E6364726D746F6F6C31"/>
        <BS bits="32" value="2"/>
        <BS ID128="0x279926496a7f5d25da69f2b3b2799a7f"/>
        <BS ID128="0x676cb88f302d10227992649885984045"/>
        <BS bits="8" string="CID=Toto"/>
        <BS ID128="0xccc0f2b3b279926496a7f5d25da692f6"/>
        <BS ID128="0xccc0f2b3b279926496a7f5d25da692d6"/>
      </DRMInfo>
      <CrypTrack IV_size="16" IsEncrypted="1" first_IV="0x0a610676cb88f302d10ac8bc66e039ed" saiSavedBox="senc" trackID="1">
        <key KID="0x279926496a7f5d25da69f2b3b2799a7f" value="0xccc0f2b3b279926496a7f5d25da692f6"/>
      </CrypTrack>
    </GPACDRM>
```

4b. Create the mpd

```
MP4Box -dash 5000 -segment-name 'outputseg-%s' -url-template -bs-switching no \
    -out output.mpd -rap \
    audio_only_encrypted.m4a \
    video_only_384kbps_encrypted.mp4
```

5b. Load the video into Osmo4 or Google Shaka.
* On Osmo4, no errors are found but the player just hangs until I kill it
* On Google Shaka, I consistently receive a player error: 
"CustomEvent {detail: Error: No DrmInfo exists!
    at shaka.media.EmeManager.buildKeySystemQueries_ (http://localhost:808…, srcElement: null, target: s…a.p…r.Player, currentTarget: s…a.p…r.Player}

The output.mpd after 5b looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!-- MPD file Generated with GPAC version 0.5.2-DEV-rev566-g4c06d0f-master  at 2015-09-03T19:17:57.544Z-->
    <MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.500S" type="static" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H0M54.424S" maxSegmentDuration="PT0H0M4.992S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:full:2011" xmlns:cenc="urn:mpeg:cenc:2013">
     <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://gpac.sourceforge.net">
      <Title>output.mpd generated by GPAC</Title>
     </ProgramInformation>

     <Period duration="PT0H0M54.424S">
      <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" lang="eng">
       <Representation id="1" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2" audioSamplingRate="48000" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="140631">
        <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2"/>
        <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" value="cenc" cenc:default_KID="27992649-6a7f-5d25-da69-f2b3b2799a7f"/>
        <SegmentTemplate timescale="48000" media="outputseg-audio_only_encrypted$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1" duration="239616" initialization="outputseg-audio_only_encryptedinit.mp4"/>
       </Representation>
      </AdaptationSet>
      <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" maxWidth="1280" maxHeight="720" maxFrameRate="24" par="16:9" lang="eng">
       <Representation id="2" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64001f" width="1280" height="720" frameRate="24" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="375052">
        <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" value="cenc" cenc:default_KID="27992649-6a7f-5d25-da69-f2b3b2799a7f"/>
        <SegmentTemplate timescale="12288" media="outputseg-video_only_384kbps_encrypted$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1" duration="46080" initialization="outputseg-video_only_384kbps_encryptedinit.mp4"/>
       </Representation>
      </AdaptationSet>
     </Period>
    </MPD>
```

Software versions:

- MP4Box: GPAC version 0.5.2-DEV-rev566-g4c06d0f-master
- FFMPEG: ffmpeg version 2.6.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Hello. I'm currently researching the subject and I did stack at the same point as you did. Did you - by any chance - solve it in the mean time?

Comment: same as Xander. Plz also have a look https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/eme